# How do I make an image responsive on a Category Page in Magento?

Tags: magento, responsive-design

I am starting to build out my category and sub category pages with Static Blocks and Products. Within my static blocks are an images slider and a products carousel. I also want to add jpegs I've created, but cannot get them responsive. What steps (if any) can I take within the static block (on the frontend) to make any images I want to include appear responsive?

Comment: Google responsive images. There are loads of techniques out there. Just beware that what might look small on the screen could still be a big jpeg!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of how you are planning to lay out your images, the simplest first step would be to create your images the same width as your desktop version's container, then:

```
 <img src="image1.jpg" class="cat-desc-image">
```

In your main CSS add:

```
 .cat-desc-image {
    float: left
    width: 100%;
 }
```